# MVC - Handling Common Key Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a question that I'm sure has already been answered.  Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

I have a standard ASP MVC site.  As with any site, I have the usual collection of key values for various aspects of the application.

```
Hair Color
10 = Green
20 = Brown
...

Status
10 = Active
20 = Paused
99 = Inactive
...

SubscriptionType
10 = 1 Week
20 = 1 Month
30 = 3 Month
...

Approval
0 = Pending Approval
10 = Approved
20 = Approved with Conditions
99 = Rejected

etc..etc..etc...
```

Normally, I have a bunch of DB tables associated with the various types but I find all the overall management of this method tedious (creating, adding values, SQL calls)

My question:

Is there a simple and straightforward way of defining and accessing these key values within the MVC code itself.  I know I can use various means (Lists, Dictionary, Hashtables, Enums, etc..) but I'm looking for something that I can easily access across various Controllers AND Views (in some Common Helper class?).  I want to be able to get the value from the key OR the reverse and get the key from the value.

I know there are probably 1000 ways to skin this cat but I'd be interested if anyone could point me to a simple and straightforward way to do it.  Is this something that could (or should) be done in the Model layer?  A Helper "CommonValues" class? Any suggestions would be welcome.

Apologies if this is "Programming 101" stuff. (I'm self taught)

Comment: If the values wont change, what is wrong with an `enum`? And all the the options you listed can be use with _Controllers AND Views_ so its not clear what your issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For integers**

You can use an [enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx), like this:

```
enum SubscriptionType
{
    OneWeek = 10,
    OneMonth = 20,
    ThreeMonths = 30
}
```

You could certainly define your enums as members of a CommonValues class, if you have one.  Or you could define them within the namespace and outside of any class, which would make them globally available.

**For strings (or integers if you like this method better)**

You can define constants as a member of a class.  Constants are exposed as static fields so they are accessible anywhere.

```
public class CommonValues
{
    public const string ColorRed = "RED";
    public const string ColorBlue = "BLUE";
    public const string WorkflowStateStopped = "STOPPED";
    public const string WorkflowStateRunning = "RUNNING";
}

//Main program
var a = CommonValues.ColorRed;
var b = CommonValues.WorkflowStateRunning;
```

Notice the messy "ColorXXX" pattern.  Seems a little 90s to me.  If you want to restrict namespaces so your intellisense works a bit more usefully, you can use a nested class.

```
public class CommonValues
{
    public class Colors
    {
        public const string Red = "RED";
        public const string Blue = "BLUE";
    }
    public class WorkflowStates
    {
        public const string Running = "RUNNING";
        public const string Stopped = "STOPPED";
    }
}

//Main program
var b = CommonValues.Colors.Red;
var c = CommonValues.WorkflowStates.Running;
```

**Display**

When it comes to display the meaning of one of these codes, naturally your display elements should come from resources, which will automatically adapt to the current culture (after all, some day you will be an international giant).  You can organize your resources with names like this:

```
var resources = new ResourceManager("CommonValues", myAssembly);

//Example for use with enum
SubscriptionType code = SubscriptionType.OneWeek;
var display = resources.GetString("SubscriptionType." + code.ToString()); //Resource ID = "SubscriptionType.OneWeek";

//Example for use with string constant
var colorCode = CommonValues.Colors.Red;
var display = resources.GetString("Colors." + colorCode); //Resource ID = "Colors.Red";
```

Comment: thanks john.  I'm mostly using integers as the key and a string as the value. the keys will be used in various tables (ex. I have a 'project' table has a column called 'status' which the value of 10 would indicate 'Active').  On the View for project, I want to quickly convert the status of 10 and show the value of "Active" on the page without doing a db join to a decode table

Comment: I've added a section on how to display these values without a trip to the DB.

Comment: john.  that's pretty much what i'm looking for.  what if i'm just given the value (ex. '10').  How do I use this to get back to "One Week".  i'm not too familiar with the ResourceManager

Comment: Yes, resources can have spaces in them.  You would create a resource with an ID of SubscriptionType.OneWeek": and a value of "One Week" (or possibly "One&nbsp;Week")

Comment: sorry edited the comment instead of adding a new one.  see my edits above.

Comment: thanks again and last q:  let's say i'm listing all my projects in my View and i have the subscription value from the db (@item.subscription - has value of 10).  how can i get back to "OneWeek"?  Do I need to create some sort of method like @item.subscription.ToLongName()?

Comment: Ah - I figured it out from your Enum explanation:  var subscriptionlongname = (CommonValues.BillingStatus)item.subscription - then i can display subscriptionlongname on the page.  thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to put in some details of what I did in case this helps others down the line.  Using John Wu's answer from above (thanks!!), here's what I did.

Create the enum.  You need to put this in some class that you can reference in the View.  I called mine EnumValues in the EnumHelper namespace.

```
namespace MyProject.EnumHelper
{
    public static class EnumValues
    {

     public enum ProjectStatus
     {
      Active = 10,
      Paused = 20,
      Inactive = 99
     }
 ...
```

So the beginning of my View looks like

```
@using MyProject.EnumHelper;
@model MyProject.Models.ProjectViewModel;
...
```

Now, if I have the integer value (say from the DB call) and I want the decoded string (ex. "Active"), I did this in the view.

```
 var projectstatus = (EnumValues.ProjectStatus)Model.project_status;
```

If I need to get the enum integer value (ex. in a dropdown), I did this in the view.

```
 var projectstatusid = (int)EnumValues.ProjectStatus.Active;
```

Thanks again to John Wu for pointing me in the right direction.